# How to sum the values of a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on some homework and I need define a function addDict(d) which adds up the values in a dictionary that looks like the following:

```
d = {'Mon':{'355':2,'451':1,'360':2},'Tue':{'451':2,'360':3},
'Thu':{'355':3,'451':2,'360':3}, 'Fri':{'355':2}, Sun':{'355':1,'451':3,'360':1}}
```

I'm having a tough time trying to figure out how I can access the values in the nested dictionaries so that I can add them up and return a single dictionary mapping those sums to the classes such as {'355': 8, '451': 8, '360': 9}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do this by converting each sub-dict into a `Counter` object and then adding them together with the `sum` function.

```
from collections import Counter
sum(map(Counter, d.values()), Counter())
# Counter({'355': 8, '360': 9, '451': 8})
```

Comment: Old trusty @coldspeed

Comment: Nice answer, as usually ;-) +1

Comment: Thanks folks :) @ChristianDean, Long time no see!

Answer (score 0):

A more heavyweight alternative to coldspeed's answer (cause you have to import pandas) would be to cast this to a pandas and build sum over rows.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(d).fillna(0).sum(1)
```

Output

```
355    8.0
360    9.0
451    8.0
dtype: float64
```